# Find Domain Names From A String

Tags: php

The following code can find www.google.com.I want to find google.com too ie domain name after space.

```
$s = 'is www.google.com equal to google.com ';
preg_match_all ("/(www)(.*)(.com|.info|.pk)/U", $s , $ma);
print_r($ma);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(www\.)?[^ ]+?(\.com|\.info|\.pk)
```

Technically does what you want with that test string. What's the purpose though, any more test cases?

Comment: that will match pretty much anything ending with `com`, `info`, or `pk`. If you want to match the `.` character in regex, you have to delimit it: `\.`. Also, you should check for one after `www`.

Comment: @wlyles Indeed! Blindly copied his version and as it worked on that test string didn't think to check it! Have amended the answer as such

Comment: i am a newbie in php , it is not copied code i created the code from http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-php-regular-expressions-for-web-developers